# Applying shopping cart price rules to one brand

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, promotions, enterprise-1.14

We have over multiple brands on our site. I want to create a rule “30% off when you spend over $100 on that brand”

Problem is if you have another brand in the cart that takes you over the $100 threshold then the discount is still being applied.

Is this possible? I feel like I’ve tried every combo.

It’s worth noting the products in the brand I want to discount are between $40-$80 so customers will need at least 2 of them in the cart. But I want people to still be able to buy other brands in the same transaction if they want.

Thanks

Comment: have you setup your brand attribute to be used for discount / promotions ?

Comment: Select promotions option yes in the brand attribute then apply cart rules.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the promotion as shown in screen shot.

[image: Apply cart rule based on selected brand]

**Note:** If you are not able to see your Brand Attribute in the list. Enable the attribute for cart rule.

Answer (score 0):

Select promotions option yes in the brand attribute then apply cart rules

1) Stores->Attribute->Products then select promotions option yes your brand attribute.

2) Marketing->Promotions->Cart Price Rules under add new rules and select brand which you apply for rules